# UI datepicker code format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

**Introduction**

I'm using the jQuery datepicker plugin in one of my applications. On one page their are multiple `input` elements which contains an instance of the `datepicker` plugin.

But each element has some differences set on the `datepicker` properties.
Also the `onSelect` event has a function that is different from each other instance.

**Example**

First element:

```
$("input[id*=txtEmployeeBirthDate]").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    showAnim: "slideDown",
    dayNamesMin: ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
    monthNamesShort: ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"],
    yearRange: "1900:2050",
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { 
        $("input[id$=hdnBirthDate]").val(dateText); 
    }
});
```

Second element:

```
$("input[id*=txtHolidayDate]").datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    showAnim: "slideDown",
    dayNamesMin: ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
    monthNamesShort: ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"],
    monthNames: ["januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"],
    yearRange: _y + ":" + _y, // _y is a private variable which contains the current year
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $("input[id$=hdnHolidayDate]").val(dateText); 
    }
});
```

**Problem**

The problem is that I have more then 5 different instances of the `datepicker` plugin.
And I would like to format or compact the code, because some properties like `dateFormat` and `monthNamesShort` are always the same.

**Question**

Is their a way to do this? Override the `datepicker`? Or what solution would be the best?

Comment: If each datepicker needs to be initialized differently than you should initialize them differently.  You could do things like creating a variable to hold your month array (or whatever is common across all the datepickers) and pass that variable to the datepicker initialization so you don't have to copy it each time you make a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a reusable object, and just extend it with the unique settings for each datepicker

```
var settings = {
    changeMonth     : true,
    changeYear      : true,
    dateFormat      : "dd-mm-yy",
    showAnim        : "slideDown",
    dayNamesMin     : ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za"],
    monthNamesShort : ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"]
}

$("input[id*=txtEmployeeBirthDate]").datepicker(
    $.extend(settings, {
        yearRange: "1900:2050",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { 
            $("input[id$=hdnBirthDate]").val(dateText); 
        }
    })
);

$("input[id*=txtHolidayDate]").datepicker(
    $.extend(settings, {
        yearRange: _y + ":" + _y,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $("input[id$=hdnHolidayDate]").val(dateText); 
        }
    })
);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7b7R/)

If these are global settings that should apply to all datepickers, you can also set them as global settings with

```
var defaults = {
    changeMonth     : true,
    ...etc
}

$.datepicker.setDefaults(defaults);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7b7R/1/)

Comment: Using the global settings do you still have to use the `$.extend()` method? Or is it good to only apply the other settings directly in the instance?